# Multiple TargetFramework with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone guide me how to target multiple frameworks with Visual studio 2017?

- netcoreapp1.1
- net46
- net45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple version in **csproj** like below-

Example1:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.0;net452</TargetFrameworks>
```

Example2:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net462</TargetFrameworks>
```

Refer [Cross-targeting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/) section.

Comment: Thank you, Sanket.  I am using VS2017 and this is what I have in my .cs proj https://kobra.io/#/e/-KhMg6mA_DvREuyBn1e0

I dont have option to paste here, please refer to the link I attached.

Comment: @Krishna.N It's `<TargetFrameworks>`, not `<TargetFramework>`.